# question about using the command rename

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I use the command `rename` to rename multiple files at the same time as follow

but how i can make more than one change in the same command

i.e. change `1 to A` and change `2 to B`

*** UPDATE 1 ***

i used the following case to test but there was errors

```
touch {1..100}
rename 's/0/A/; s/1/B/; s/2/C/; s/3/D/; s/4/E/; s/5/F/; s/6/G/; s/7/H/;s/8/I/; s/9/J/' *
```

the result is

```
ls 
B    BE  C   CF  D3  DG  EA  EH  FB  FI  GC  GJ  HD  I   IE  J9  JF
B1   BF  C2  CG  DA  DH  EB  EI  FC  FJ  GD  H   HE  I8  IF  JA  JG
BA   BG  CA  CH  DB  DI  EC  EJ  FD  G   GE  H7  HF  IA  IG  JB  JH
BA0  BH  CB  CI  DC  DJ  ED  F   FE  G6  GF  HA  HG  IB  IH  JC  JI
BC   BI  CD  CJ  DE  E   EF  F5  FG  GA  GH  HB  HI  IC  IJ  JD
BD   BJ  CE  D   DF  E4  EG  FA  FH  GB  GI  HC  HJ  ID  J   JE
```

*** Update 2 ***

to solve the issue , i must use the /g  . i.e 11 should be BB but to do that /g is required otherwise only the first number will be changed

so the correct command is

```
rename 's/0/A/g; s/1/B/g; s/2/C/g; s/3/D/g; s/4/E/g; s/5/F/g; s/6/G/g; s/7/H/g; s/8/I/g ; s/9/J/g ' *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert multiple conversion patterns separated by `;`:

```
rename 's/1/A/; s/2/B/' *
```

If you want to change all occurrences of `1` and `2` rather than only the first ones, use the `g` (global) modifier:

```
rename 's/1/A/g; s/2/B/g' *
```

**Example:**

```
$ ls -1
1234
4321
foo12bar
spam23egg
test

$ rename -n 's/1/A/; s/2/B/' *
1234 renamed as AB34
4321 renamed as 43BA
foo12bar renamed as fooABbar
spam23egg renamed as spamB3egg

$ rename 's/1/A/; s/2/B/' *

$ ls -1
43BA
AB34
fooABbar
spamB3egg
test
```

Answer (score 6):

This is also possible by using one `rename` command:

```
rename 'y/A-B/1-2/' *
```

---

Example : the `-n` switch means "No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename."

```
$ rename -n 'y/A-B/1-2/' *
rename(A, 1)
rename(B, 2)
```

---

*Transliteration?*

```
y/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr

Transliterates all occurrences of the characters found in the search list
with the corresponding character in the replacement list. It returns the
number of characters replaced or deleted.
```

<sub>[Source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)</sub>

Comment: @A.B. thanks for the idea , it will help in case the change is sequential letters , but this is just an example

Comment: @kos what do you with translation ?

Comment: @FatMind It's just the name of the `y///` command: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/y.html

Comment: @kos, Thx for the link, added =)